# I apparently have an optional in my code, but the compiler thinks I haven't

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have this function:

```
func getTodaysDate() -> (day: String, date: String) {

    let currentDate = Date()
    let monthFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()

    monthFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    monthFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let month = monthFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

    dayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    dayFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let dayToday = dayFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([NSCalendar.Unit.day], from: currentDate)
    let day = String(describing: dateComponents.day)

    let date = ("\(month) \(day!)")

    return (day: dayToday.uppercased(), date: date.uppercased())

}
```

Which should return:

> FRIDAY, APRIL 21

But instead it returns:

> FRIDAY, APRIL OPTIONAL (21)

Which I don't get, because the constant 'day' is not an optional. Even when I try unwrapping it the compiler complains that it

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'

Has anyone an idea what is going on?

Comment: Isn't `dateComponents.day` an Optional? If you use an Optional in a String initializer, you will get the dreaded "Optional" literal. Unwrap this property before using it in the String initializer.

Comment: What Eric said, what you need is an

`if let dayAsInt = dateComponents.day { ... }`

because .day is an optional, see https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponents/1779808-day

Comment: `String(describing: dateComponents.day)` doesn't unwrap the optional, it just prints the debug description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3 (unlike Swift 2) all date components are optional:

```
var day: Int? { get set }
```

---

The error occurred because you created a string from an optional `Int`. The result is a non-optional string but it contains literal "Optional()"

```
let day = String(describing: dateComponents.day) // --> "Optional(21)"
```

Apart from the redundant creation of a string from a string with String Interpolation the compiler complains because the string is not an optional. The literal "Optional()" is irrelevant.

```
let date = ("\(month) \(day!)")
```

The correct syntax is

```
let day = dateComponents.day!
let date = ("\(month) \(day)")
```

---

I recommend to use native Swift 3 syntax (no bridging to `NSCalendar`)

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: currentDate)
let day = dateComponents.day! // needs to be unwrapped.

let date = ("\(month) \(day)")
```

Since you need only one component, there is an easier syntax (non-optional)

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: currentDate)

let date = ("\(month) \(day)")
```

Comment: The easier syntax works perfectly. Thank you very much.